# Can 2 sequential fetch PUT requests get processed out of order?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, put

Can 2 sequential fetch PUT requests made by same client get processed out of order by server cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which scenario you're giving us.

Yes, `fetch` requests are asynchronous and does not support synchronous calls.

You could make them synchronous by making one call after the other

*Code is contrived, it'll not work but it'll demonstrate the gist of it.*

```
fetch().then(res => return fetch());
```

or with [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
let res = await fetch();
let res2 = await fetch();
```

There is no built-in way, as you can see, to make `fetch` synchronous.

If your code looks like this, without async/await or `.then()`.

```
let res = fetch();
let res2 = fetch();
```

Then it's totally possible, and most likely, that your server cluster will process these out of order since each call to `fetch` will spawn a request and most likely take a thread in your application server thus processing it "whenever".